# JPanel and JFrame coordinate messed up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to write a game using JPanle and JFrame. I set up a panel inside a frame. When I paint on the panel with a rectangle size of the panel at 0,0. The rectangle shifts up and left for some pixels. How do I fix this problem? I googled and I saw the insets method, but I don't want to use that calculate my coordinate everytime I draw.

Here are the codes

```
public class Game extends JFrame{

public Game(){
    this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));  
    pane p = new pane();
    this.getContentPane().add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    pack();
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);


}


public static void main(String[] args){
    new Game();
}

}
```

---

```
public class pane extends JPanel{

public pane(){

setDoubleBuffered(false);
setBackground(Color.black);
setPreferredSize( new Dimension(800, 600));

setFocusable(true);
requestFocus(); 
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

}
}
```

[screen shot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2p03.png)

Comment: setDoubleBuffered(false); normally merely causes flickering.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. BTW, in Swing the method for implmenting custom painting is paintComponent (_not_ paint)

Comment: I do know the naming conventions, but I was too lazy to do it in a testing code example, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no shift of your panel, it is located in 0,0. The problem is that the panel actually gets a size of 810,610 instead of 800,600. For some reason (which so far I was unable to find and if somebody has an idea I would love to learn), when you call `setResizable(false)` on a `JFrame`, its insets are modified and eventually this leads to your content pane to be bigger than expected (at least on JDK6/Win7). Call `setResizable(false)` before adding the components and packing the frame, and it works.

Also consider painting a rectangle of the size of your panel (`g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` so that you are sure to fill the entire area, no matter what happens.

Any reason to fill the background with white color and then replace it with black?

Comment: +1 given,prfectly working"_g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()_"

Comment: we can add "_setUndecoratied(true)_"to code to hide the extra space

Comment: Thanks, the setResizable works, but I don't know why it does. The point is not to paint the whole frame, I just wanted to have accurate coordinate to paint on, and not get my drawing shifted. And using setUndecoratied will hide the title bar and the buttons.

Comment: @user1503395 for some obscure reason the insets of the JFrame are modified when you call `setResizable(false)`. Insets are part of the size of the frame. So first you call pack (while not resizable) and the frame gets a given size. After that you call `setResizable(false)` which reduces the insets resulting in your content pane getting bigger than expected. So just make sure that pack is called after `setResizable(false)`. In all cases, your panel is never shifted!